Error while Converting jsonNode to Jsonpatch
"Cannot deserialize value of type java.util.ArrayList<com.github.fge.jsonpatch.JsonPatchOperation> from Object value (token JsonToken.FIELD_NAME)\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type java.util.ArrayList<com.github.fge.jsonpatch.JsonPatchOperation> from Object value (token JsonToken.FIELD_NAME)\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1752)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1526)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1473)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:396)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:252)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:28)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1402)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromO
while this line modifiedJsonPatch = JsonPatch.fromJson(modifiedJsonNode); i was getting this error,
modifiedJsonNode node value :{"op":"add","path":"/details","value":["NAME","DATE"]}.
